# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ComponentSelectionReason.getDescription()Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: java, android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm using latest version of Ionic Framework and trying to run my app through Android studio. I can run it in my phone through terminal with this command `ionic cap run android -lc --external` but in AS I'm facing this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ComponentSelectionReason.getDescription()Ljava/lang/String;

Is there anyway to resolve this error or to deploy app on Play Store without AS?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by updating Android Studio. Actually this error was saying "Failed to notify build listener" which can be solved by updating Android Studio [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56504853/how-to-fix-failed-to-notify-build-listener-error). I followed the updating steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133518/how-to-update-android-studio-automatically). The older version of AS can't run new ionic projects, so kindly update to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is solved updating android studio :)